# How to load a webpage on WebView from locally-created folder?

Tags: javascript, android, html, android-studio, webview

Working with **Android-Studio**, I am trying to use **WebView** to load a local **html file** that contains **javascript**.

First, I created an `assets` folder inside the `Java` folder. Then, I created two folders inside assets folder: `html` and `scripts`. I put my `index.html` page inside html folder and the `index.js` file inside scripts folder. The two paths look like the following in Android-Studio:

1. *app/java/assets/html/index.html*
2. *app/java/assets/scripts/index.js*

Now, when I try to load the index.html, I use the following syntax:

```
myWebView.loadUrl("file:///assets/html/index.html");
```

but it is not working. I also used each of the following:

```
myWebView.loadUrl("file://assets/html/index.html");

myWebView.loadUrl("file://android_assets/html/index.html");

myWebView.loadUrl("file:///android_assets/html/index.html");
```

Still, when the page loads, it shows "Webpage not available"!!

The app works fine, the intent start and a webpage loads with the above warning message.

1. What is right syntax to load the webpage from a local-created folder ?
2. What is the right syntax for loading index.js inside the index.html ?

---

**Here is the code**:

```
    public class DisplayMessageActivity extends Activity {

    private WebView myWebView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_display_message);

        myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
        myWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        myWebView.loadUrl("file:///android_assets/html/index.html"); // doesn't work
        // myWebView.loadUrl("http://www.example.com"); // works
    }
```

---

**UPDATE**

Here is the `index.html` :

```
<html>
<header><title>This is title</title></header>
<body>
Hello world
</body>
</html>
```

No javascript at the moment.

Comment: please show content of your index.html. You might have incorrect reference to index.js. Please use this format mWebView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/html/index.html"); To isolate issue with index.js. Please create a hello_world.html and try loading in html to see if that's loaded correctly

Comment: @AmodGokhale : I am already using a raw hello_world html file (please check the update). At the moment, I am just trying to load the correct page. But it is not working !!

Comment: never mind.. for android studio file should be located @ /app/src/main/assets/html/index.html and then load using file:///android_asset/html/index.html

Comment: @AmodGokhale .. No error at the logcat ..

Comment: @AmodGokhale : It shows the exact path you mentioned, but why it is not loading the hello_world page !!

Comment: no.. you have created assets folder inside java.. it should be /src/main/assets/... file name.. your path is app/java/assets

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/122988/discussion-between-amod-gokhale-and-suda-nese).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create assets folder under main ( not inside java ) and then use

```
myWebView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/html/index.html");
```

not

```
myWebView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset**s**/html/index.html");
```

[image]

Comment: I corrected the path. Now when I use : `myWebView.loadUrl("http://www.example.com");` it works. But when I use : `myWebView.loadUrl("file:///android_assets/html/index.html");` it doesn't !!

Comment: did you moved your files main/assets/html/index.html? it shouldn't be main/java/assets/html/index.html

Comment: Yes I did . Now, the path is : `main/assets/html/index.html` (as it looks on the *Android* & *project* preservatives on the left).

Comment: The exact message is : *The webpage at file://android_assets/html/index.html might be temporarily down or it may have moved permanently to a new web address.*

Comment: please upload structure screenshot of your assets folder

Comment: and it's file:///android_asset/ not file:///android_assets/ I have updated my answer

Comment: OK, IT WORKS NOW .. guess what, removing the last "s" letter in "android_assets" made all the difference. Thanks a lot

Comment: Kindly please highlight the "s" issue in your answer.

Answer (score 3):

Use above answer just replace

```
webView.loadUrl("file://android_asset/index.html");
```

with `webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/index.html");`